# clearInterval inside of socket getStates function

Tags: javascript, socket.io, setinterval, clearinterval

I try to use a modified socket.io adaption for iobroker (smart home broker) with a setInterval function for showing every second the time ago of the last received timestamp of

It works so far, till the second updated timestamp comes... It seems `clearInterval` did not stop the interval and the timer is running twice with the old and new timestamp.

How and where do i have to `clearInterval` correctly?

**Updated**:
If `onUpdate` activates the `servConn.getStates([stromvIDts]`function and received a new timestamp of stromvIDts, the interval should run and show the time ago (every second updated). If (after around 2-3 min) a new value is there, the interval should stop and a new one starting and showing every second the past time of the new timestamp, e.g. "some seconds ago"... 2 Minutes ago ...)

My code:

```js
servConn.namespace = 'mobile.0';
servConn._useStorage = false;

var stromv = 'hm-rpc.1.MEQ123456.1.POWER';

var subscriptions = [stromv];

var states = [];

servConn.init({
  name: 'mobile.0',
  connLink: 'http://IP:8082',
  socketSession: ''

}, {

  onConnChange: function(isConnected) {

    if (isConnected) {
      console.log('connected');

    } else {
      console.log('disconnected');
    }
  },

  onUpdate: function(id, state) {

    setTimeout(function() {

      states[id] = state;

      let stromvID = states[stromv].val;
      let stromvIDts = states[stromv].ts;

      //Get States of subsribed states if changed
      servConn.getStates([stromvID], (error, states) => {
        document.getElementById("stromvAktuell").innerHTML = stromvID + " W/h";
      });

      servConn.getStates([stromvIDts], (error, states) => {

        function stopInterval() {
          clearInterval(timerId);
        };

        timerId = setInterval(function() {
          updateTimeAgo();
        }, 1000);

        function updateTimeAgo() {
          let duration = moment(stromvIDts).fromNow();
          console.log(duration);
          document.getElementById("stromvTs").innerHTML = duration;
        };

      });

    }, 0);

  },

  onError: function(err) {
    window.alert(_('Cannot execute %s for %s, because of insufficient permissions', err.command, err.arg), _('Insufficient permissions'), 'alert', 600);
  }

}, false, false);

servConn._socket.emit('subscribe', subscriptions);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
  <title>TEST</title>
  <script src="http://IP:8082/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="../tmp/conn.js"></script>
  <script src="moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <script>
    moment.locale('de')
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    Value: <b id="stromvAktuell">unknown</b>
    <br> Last update: <b id="stromvTs">unknown</b>
    <br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try putting your `getStates` function inside of `onConnChange` instead of `onUpdate` like the [example](https://github.com/ioBroker/ioBroker.socketio/blob/master/example/index.html) suggests

Comment: The `onConnChange` function will only update the `getStates` when the client connection to the websocket server changes (i.e. browser refresh, connection lost...) , but not when there are new states available.  In production case you must use both, the `onUpdate' function if new data should be pushed when available, no doubt about this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new intervals and clearing the old one, just start one interval and update the value every time `onUpdate` runs:

If you want the time since the last update, you can use `Date.now()`.

```js
servConn.namespace = 'mobile.0';
servConn._useStorage = false;

var stromv = 'hm-rpc.1.MEQ123456.1.POWER';

var subscriptions = [stromv];

var states = [];

let lastTimestamp = -1;

let duration = -1;

timerId = setInterval(function() {
  updateTimeAgo();
}, 1000);

function updateTimeAgo() {
  console.log(Date.now() - lastTimeStamp);
  document.getElementById("stromvTs").innerHTML = Integer((Date.now() - lastTimeStamp)/1000);
};

servConn.init({
  name: 'mobile.0',
  connLink: 'http://IP:8082',
  socketSession: ''

}, {

  onConnChange: function(isConnected) {

    if (isConnected) {
      console.log('connected');
      lastTimestamp = Date.now();
    } else {
      console.log('disconnected');
    }
  },

  onUpdate: function(id, state) {

    setTimeout(function() {

      states[id] = state;

      let stromvID = states[stromv].val;
      let stromvIDts = states[stromv].ts;

      //Get States of subsribed states if changed
      servConn.getStates([stromvID], (error, states) => {
        document.getElementById("stromvAktuell").innerHTML = stromvID + " W/h";
      });
      
      lastTimeStamp = Date.now();

    }, 0);

  },

  onError: function(err) {
    window.alert(_('Cannot execute %s for %s, because of insufficient permissions', err.command, err.arg), _('Insufficient permissions'), 'alert', 600);
  }

}, false, false);

servConn._socket.emit('subscribe', subscriptions);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
  <title>TEST</title>
  <script src="http://IP:8082/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="../tmp/conn.js"></script>
  <script src="moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <script>
    moment.locale('de')
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    Value: <b id="stromvAktuell">unknown</b>
    <br> Last update: <b id="stromvTs">unknown</b>
    <br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!   Now the interval shows always: 
'Last update: in ein paar Sekunden' and never changed this..

Expected behaviour is:
..some seconds ago
.. 1 Minute ago
.. 2 Minutes ago

Comment: Maybe my question and goal is a bit unclear.

If onUpdate got a new value of stromvIDts, the interval should run and show the time ago (every second updated). If (after around 2-3 min) a new value is there, the interval should be stopped/cleared and a new one starts with the new timeAgo of the timestamp.

Comment: use `date.now();` i have updated my answer

Comment: Sorry, but we are moving more away from the goal. 

The interval must use the variable `stromvIDts` and format it with `moment(stromvIDts).fromNow();` every second. The variable is refreshed by `servConn.getStates([stromvIDts])`, which runs if the socket callback function `onUpdate:` is receiving new states.  This `getStates` function must not be deleted in the code.

Your example did never update the html div `stromvTs`.  The console shows:
`lastTimeStamp is not defined`
`Integer is not defined`

Comment: @KaiL. You're going to need to update your post to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that I can help you implement that. The code you originally posted results in some errors.

Comment: Well, the minimized code i have postetd works on my side, without any errors, because of the working socket connection.  I do not have a clue, how i could simulate the socket connection with that callback functions working for testing purposes here.  However, thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: @KaiL. Alternatively, you could direct me to the documentation of those specific functions and I can try to understand what those functions need to do.

Comment: Thanks again!  As far as i understand, everything of my code is inside of a client callback function, which connects to the socket.io adaption of ioBroker (which is a nodejs/js broker for my smart home).  With an ioBroker specific adapter and the special written `conn.js` for connections between the client and the websocket server (the iobroker adapter) you can get the states with their values of all integrated smarthome components. So i am able to receive "live" data in my browser or visualisation, without e.g. refreshing the browser.

Comment: The docu of this websocket adaption is here:  
[link] https://github.com/ioBroker/ioBroker.socketio [/link] and as well an basic example in the same named folder. This is what i used and what works.
The problem is, that the setInterval function is called every time again in a new instance and cannot be stopped, if inside the `onUpdate` and `getStates` callback functions (as you mentioned already).  But i guess it must be inside this callback functions, because this ones received new states, if the websocket server has one and received them to the client.